# Hot water valve in the basement (how do I turn it off?)

Tags: water, ceiling, valve

My tub faucet is leaking.  I know how to fix it,  But the shut off valve is in the center of basement ceiling and  of course it's stuck.

But that's not the question.  I can approach this valve from any angle.

What should I look for to determine the point from where I should turn it?  (N S E W?)   Any ideas?

Comment: We're going to need a picture of the valve. There are many different types.

Comment: Odds are good that it's _clockwise_ to turn _off_ and _counterclockwise_ (or anticlockwise if you prefer) to turn _on_ whether it's a quarter turn, a full turn or multiple turns. It shouldn't matter much which direction the valve is facing.

Comment: `N S E W?` ... since when do valves use cardinal points for orientation? ... your question makes absolutely no sense

Comment: Sometimes backing off the [packing nut](https://www.familyhandyman.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/FH02OCT_02777_008-fix-leaky-water-shutoff-cutaway.jpg?w=1200) _slightly_ (<1/12 turn) will allow the valve stem to turn. This will usually be accompanied by leaking around the stem which _might_ be willing to abate when the packing nut is tightened. Have a rag handy (bucket optional), know where the main shutoff is (and that it works), and have a professional on speed-dial before starting.

Comment: @HABO Perhaps shut off the main valve FIRST. Just saying.

Comment: "*What should I look for to determine the point from where I should turn it? (N S E W?)*"  Look for  an object large enough to hide behind but allows you to keep watch,  wait for it to let down its defenses and then slowly sneak up on it.  If you are in the northern hemisphere then you sneak up on it from the south, visa versa for the southern hemisphere.

Answer (score 1):

The green arrow shows the direction to turn to close it.
The purple arrow shows the *packing nut* discussed in the comments.

I'm not sure what you mean about North, South, etc but if this thing is installed in the ceiling with the red handle pointing up, you could stand directly below it,  reach up and over it with your hand to grab it from above, then turn your body to the right.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have a 1/4 turn ball valve then there should be stops protruding from the unit which prevent it from being turned too far. Look for something similar to this picture and you'll be able to determine the proper direction of rotation.

In this picture it is in the ON position, parallel to the water line. You need to make the handle perpendicular (imagine the letter T) to shut the water OFF.

If it feels seized up then make sure to hold the pipe firmly because copper is a soft metal and you could deform (or worse, rupture) it while trying to turn your valve. If in doubt then it's time to call a plumber.

[image]

---

If you have a gate valve then righty-tighty, lefty-loosey :)

Comment: how did you add this photo.  I would like to add the photos of my value (both sides)  from the ceiling in  the middle of my basement.  What side is the side I turn from.  Maybe they will help, or the orientation will make my question understandable.  Thanks

Comment: @RITAaLUGRINE I do not believe you have enough reputation to insert a photo into your post but if you upload an image to a free hosting service such as https://imgbb.com/ and provide the URL then I will gladly add it into your question :-)

Comment: Thank you I can't see this valve from above, as it was installed facing the ceiling. That adds to the confusion.   The pipe is in the middle of the basement.  I can approach it from either side, facing east or west.  The valve is tight, so I'm trying to loosen it a bit at a time.  I just don't know if I'm tightening it or loosening it depending on where I'm standing.  Here's a link to the type of valve.  Thanks again. https://brickseek.com/lowes-inventory-checker?sku=3506544

Comment: That's a gate valve. It should spin clockwise. Those valves are notorious for corroding and seizing. You might not be able to turn it off if that's the case.

Comment: Yeah, was getting to the conclusion, too.  It was just I wasn't sure that if I stood on one side (west) or the other (east) if I was loosening or tightening.

Comment: @RITAaLUGRINE I couldn't possibly tell you unless you provided a picture and designated North, East, South, and West. Spin it clockwise to shut it off.